# How to filter the nested object based on the status INVALID

Tags: javascript

```
    var testObject = {
      address: { form: 1, status: "VALID" },
      address2: {form: 1,  status: "INVALID" },
      address3: {form: 1,  status: "INVALID" }
    }
  Object.keys(testObject)
  .filter(key => console.log(key))
```

What I'm trying to do here is to filter the data based on the status INVALID.

example output should be like this.

```
{
  address2: { form: 1, status: "INVALID" },
  address3: { form: 1, status: "INVALID" }
}
```

or

```
[
  { address2: { form: 1, status: "INVALID" } },
  { address3: { form: 1, status: "INVALID" } }
]
```

Comment: you need to convert object to array, use filter method, and convert it back into the object

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

```
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(testObject).filter(x => x[1].status === "INVALID"))
```

Long:

```
const objectConvertedToArray = Object.entries(testObject)
const filteredArray = objectConvertedToArray.filter(([key, val] => val === "INVALID"))
const filteredObject = Object.fromEntries(filteredArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and add the properties that match to a new object.

```js
var testObject = {
  address: { form: 1, status: "VALID" },
  address2: { form: 1,  status: "INVALID" },
  address3: { form: 1,  status: "INVALID" }
}

const out = {};

for (let [key, obj] of Object.entries(testObject)) {
  if (obj.status === 'INVALID') out[key] = obj;
}

console.log(out);
```

If you want an array [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the object on to an array using the key.

```js
var testObject = {
  address: { form: 1, status: "VALID" },
  address2: { form: 1,  status: "INVALID" },
  address3: { form: 1,  status: "INVALID" }
}

const out = [];

for (let [key, obj] of Object.entries(testObject)) {
  if (obj.status === 'INVALID') out.push({ [key]: obj });
}

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick **without changing the original object**:

```js
var testObject = {
  address: { form: 1, status: "VALID" },
  address2: {form: 1,  status: "INVALID" },
  address3: {form: 1,  status: "INVALID" }
}

var ouput = Object.keys(testObject).reduce((obj, element) => {
  if(testObject[element].status === 'INVALID') obj[element] = testObject[element]

  return obj
}, {})

console.log(ouput)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updating existing object =>**

```js
      var testObject = {
          address: { form: 1, status: "VALID" },
          address2: {form: 1,  status: "INVALID" },
          address3: {form: 1,  status: "INVALID" }
        }

        Object
          .keys(testObject)
          .filter(k => testObject[k].status !== "INVALID")
          .forEach(k => delete testObject[k]);
          
      console.log(testObject);
```

**Creating New array =>**

```js
          var testObject = {
              address: { form: 1, status: "VALID" },
              address2: {form: 1,  status: "INVALID" },
              address3: {form: 1,  status: "INVALID" }
            }

          var result = 
            Object
              .keys(testObject)
              .filter(k => testObject[k].status === "INVALID")
              .map(k => {
                var obj = {};
                obj[k] = testObject[k];
                return obj;
              });
              
          console.log(result);
```

Comment: OP wants the object  back, not the array

Comment: @NafisIslam what if it will return to array instead of object?

Comment: @BeginnerCoder do you want an array?

Comment: @NafisIslam yes. can you do separate for the object and array.

Answer (score 0):

[`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) -> to get both keys and values of object.

`.forEach` -> to run through all entries.

[`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) -> keyword to delete property of an object

```js
var testObject = {
      address: { form: 1, status: "VALID" },
      address2: {form: 1,  status: "INVALID" },
      address3: {form: 1,  status: "INVALID" }
    }
Object.entries(testObject)
  .forEach(([key,val]) => { if(val.status !== "INVALID") delete testObject[key]; });
  console.log(testObject);
```